# telegram-python-bot ImportError No module named 'cryptography' Alpine Docker

Tags: python, docker, cryptography, alpine-linux

I am trying to run script which sends message to telegram using python-telegram-bot module.
The script runs in docker on alpine.

The script cannot import Telegram, I get an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'

My docker file

```
FROM nickgryg/alpine-pandas:3.7.7 as base
FROM base as builder

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir /install
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev 
WORKDIR /install
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --install-option="--prefix=/install" -r /requirements.txt
FROM base
COPY --from=builder /install /usr/local
COPY src /app
RUN apk --no-cache add libpq 
WORKDIR /app
```

requirements.txt is below

```
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
Django==3.0.3
future==0.18.2
idna==2.9
pandas==1.0.3
pycountry==19.8.18
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.8
vertica-python==0.10.3
currencyconverter==0.14.1
python-telegram-bot==12.6.1
psycopg2==2.8.5
```

I also tried to add line `add apk py3-cryptography` to dockerfile but that didn't help.

I found many questions related to issues with cryptography but no solutions helped.

Comment: Show us your python source code that you copy into container in `COPY src /app` line

Comment: Run `python -m pip install <your-module>`

Comment: Could you post the full output of your `docker build` command?

Comment: try to add this library `libssl-dev`

Comment: libressl-dev should be used for alpine, I tried it and nothing worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to resolve it myself. As the image is built in two stages I don't install cryptography during the first stage now, it is packaged into a wheel file. Which will then be copied and installed in the new image.

```
FROM nickgryg/alpine-pandas as base
FROM base as builder

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir /install
RUN apk update && apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev libc-dev postgresql-dev 
WORKDIR /install
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --install-option="--prefix=/install" -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /wheels
WORKDIR /wheels
RUN pip wheel cryptography

FROM base
RUN apk add libressl
COPY --from=builder /install /usr/local
COPY --from=builder /wheels /wheels
RUN pip install /wheels/*.whl
COPY src /app
RUN apk --no-cache add libpq 
WORKDIR /app
```

Answer (score 0):

The image you're using is alpine. If you're having a dependency on cryptography module, then follow the below steps to get it fixed.

### **Building cryptography on Linux**

`Cryptography` ships `manylinux` wheels (as of 2.0) so all dependencies are included. For users on pip 8.1 or above running on a `manylinux1` or `manylinux2010` compatible distribution (almost everything except `Alpine`) all you should need to do is:

```sh
$ pip install cryptography
```

If you are on Alpine or just want to compile it yourself then cryptography requires a compiler, headers for Python (if you're not using `pypy`), and headers for the `OpenSSL` and `libffi` libraries available on your system.

### Alpine

Replace `python3-dev` with `python-dev` if you're using Python 2.

```sh
$ sudo apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev
```

If you get an error with `openssl-dev` you may have to use `libressl-dev.`

So making the changes on the above `apk` given packages in your Dockerfile should work.

Just in case, if you want more details for other OS distributions, it can be found in section **[Building cryptography on Linux](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux)** on the [**Cryptography Official Site**](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) and [**Cryptography GitHub**](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But these are guidelines from cryptography's official installation guide. I've already tried it, didn't help. All the requested libs are in my dockerfile and this can be seen in my question